# Opening different file extensions and installing plugins in cefpython3

Tags: python-3.6, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I am using django for my web application. At client side i am using cef browser (cefpython3). My aim is to open a file in the web browser itself. For now i am able to open .txt, .py, .pdf, .png, .jpeg, .mp3 and .mp4 extensions.

1. How to open these files in separate window as they gets opened in the same window ?
2. .mp4 files sometimes won't play. But when they do, they do so without volume controls and muted ?
3. Are there any plugins for vlc and notepad++ for cef browser, if so how to install them ?
4. Also want to open .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt and .pptx formats.....any suggestions how to achieve  it ?
5. How to install plugins in cefpython3 in general and any site where i can find them ? (subpart of 3)

Thank you